# Translation: "In the past, I often encountered hungry (badly) people"

Tags: translation

I want to say the sentence "In the past, I often encountered hungry (badly) people". Is any of these correct?:

- 过去，我经常遇到饿坏的人
- 过去，我经常遇到饿坏**了**的人

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 过去，我经常遇到饿坏的人 - In the past, I often encounter starving people.
- 过去，我经常遇到饿坏了的人  - In the past, I often encounter starved people.

Here, 了 put emphasis on the effect of starvation and acts as the past tense indicator as well.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct

1. 饿坏的人 --> [饿(v) + 坏(result complement) + 的(adjective marker) + 人(noun)
2. 饿坏了的人 --> [饿(v) + 坏(result complement) + 了(word particle indicates the verb is completed) + 的(adjective marker) + 人(noun)

- [饿坏的(adj)]+ [人]
- [饿坏了的(adjectival phrase) + [人]

The difference between adjectives and adjectival phrases is adjectives are usually a set term, no longer than three characters and adjectival phrases can be a whole sentence long

Example:

- 饥饿的，绝望的，垂死的人 --> 饥饿，绝望，垂死的人
- 饿坏了的，面臨绝望的，在垂死挣扎的人

Answer (score 0):

My translation is: 我曾经常常遇上饿坏了的人

曾经 means "in the past."
饿坏了 is customary.

Also, if you want to use 过去, you need to use 在过去, which means "in the past."

Comment: Are you sure about the last comment?  [YouDao](https://youdao.com/result?word=lj%3A%E8%BF%87%E5%8E%BB&lang=en) gives the examples (i) 过去她受过男人的虐待, (ii) 过去我常去那里, (iii) 过去人们每天都来看他.

Comment: 过去 is not a commonly used term in Chinese. In fact, it is almost never used. Intead, use 曾经 or 曾.  If you insist on using 过去, it's better to put it after the subject. For example 她过去受过男人的虐待. Or perhaps as I suggested  在过去, 她受过男人的虐待

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what:

> In the past I often encountered hungry (badly) people.

is supposed to mean. I assume you mean this:

In the past I often encountered very hungry people.
过去我经常遇到非常饥饿的人。